# Exception while using Map as a property in a bean when using Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I would like to store a Map property in my bean and want it to be stored in MongoDB using Spring Data Mongodb.

```
public class Sample {
   Map values;
   //constructor, getters and setters go here
}
```

The saving happens fine.  Assume that I have saved a Mongo document like this using this bean:

```
{
  "values": {
     "id":123,
     "name":"Vivek"
   }
 }
```

Now, I would like to query back this document.  So, I write something like this:

```
 Query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("values.id").is(123));
```

This results in an exception while executing the `find()`.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:123)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:69)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:290)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:274)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper$MetadataBackedField.getPath(QueryMapper.java:559)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper$MetadataBackedField.<init>(QueryMapper.java:486)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObject(QueryMapper.java:104)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1489)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1480)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:527)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:518)
```

How can we get out of this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change `Map values;` to `Map<Object,Object> values;` and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("values._id").is(id));

    query.fields().include("values.$");

    Sample sample= mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Sample.class,"sample");

    Map values= sample.getValues();
```

if you still faces the same problem try changing the name values as seems like a reserved word maybe.